# AWS StepFunctions: Error While creating State Machine using AWS-SDK through lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a state machine in AWS stepfunctions using AWS sdk Eg.,

```
stepfunctions.createStateMachine(params, function(err, data)...
```

I created a lambda in AWS console and added the code for creating state machine. Also I provided the permissions for the Role to execute this lambda and create state machine. I verified the Role Permissions using Simulator also which is fine (allowed). But when I execute the lambda, I am getting AcccessDeniedException.

```
   errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::555555555:assumed-role/SFN_API_role/SFAPITest is not authorized to perform: states:CreateStateMachine on resource: arn:aws:states:us-east-1:555555555:stateMachine:*",
  "errorType": "AccessDeniedException
```

"SFN_API_role" is the role  and "SFAPITest" is the lambda.
Here is the Policy defined:

```
 {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "states:ListStateMachines",
            "states:ListActivities",
            "states:CreateStateMachine",
            "states:CreateActivity"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "lambda:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "states:DescribeStateMachine",
            "states:StartExecution",
            "states:DeleteStateMachine",
            "states:ListExecutions"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "states:DescribeExecution",
            "states:GetExecutionHistory",
            "states:StopExecution"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "states:DescribeActivity",
            "states:DeleteActivity",
            "states:GetActivityTask",
            "states:SendTaskSuccess",
            "states:SendTaskFailure",
            "states:SendTaskHeartbeat"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: I think the log is clear enough - access denied exception which means that the role that you have assumed does not have permissions to create state machines

Answer (score 1):

You are using `"Resource": ["*"]` instead of `"Resource": "*"`. Just change the first portion of your policy to the following:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "states:ListStateMachines",
            "states:ListActivities",
            "states:CreateStateMachine",
            "states:CreateActivity"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
...
```